# how to declare floating numbers as being float128 with numba

Tags: numba

I am concerned about numerical error n my simulation and want numba to use `float128` variables. When I specify `nb.jit('f8()')` on `func_nb`, I tell numba that the function takes no arguments and returns a `float128` number, right? How can I tell numba to make all the floating point numbers `float128`?

```
@nb.jit()
def f_big_nb(A, k, std_A, std_k, mean_A=10, mean_k=0.2, hh=100):
    return ( 1 / (std_A * std_k * 2 * np.pi) ) * A * (hh/50) ** k * np.exp( -1*(k - mean_k)**2 / (2 * std_k **2 ) - (A - mean_A)**2 / (2 * std_A**2))

@nb.jit('f8()')
def func_nb():
    outer_sum = 0
    dk = 0.01 #0.000001
    X = np.arange(dk, 0.4, dk)
    Y = np.arange(dk, 20, dk)
    for i in xrange(X.shape[0]):
        k = X[i] # faster to do lookup than iterate over an array directly
        inner_sum = 0
        for j in xrange(Y.shape[0]):
            A = Y[j]
            inner_sum += dk * f_big_nb(A, k, 1e-5, 1e-5)
        outer_sum += inner_sum * dk

    return outer_sum
```

Comment: I don't think numba supports float128, and for that matter numpy's is sort of spotty - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/basics.types.html#extended-precision.

Comment: `f8` is a 64 bit float - it probably is "fine" for whatever you're doing (and will be much faster) unless you have very specific requirements.